# Change it_outtab after the first display (ALV grid)

Tags: abap, alv

Is it possible to change the `it_outtab`, i.e the data of my alv without destroying it?

I know that to change the field catalog it is possible with this method:

```
CALL METHOD gr_alvpl->set_frontend_fieldcatalog
  EXPORTING
    it_fieldcatalog = gt_fldct.


CALL METHOD gr_alvpl->refresh_table_display( ).
```

But if I have to change the `it_outtab` parameters, is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the table structure or the contents of the table?

Comment: the content of the table

Comment: ….yes? You’ve already mentioned the method you need in the question - so what IS your question?

Comment: @shmoolki Please give more hints on what you are trying to achieve. Some minimal working example would be nice.

Comment: @vwegert What i wrote it s just to change the field catalog but i want to change the data of the alv, i'll edit the question to add more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the method `REFRESH_TABLE_DISPLAY`, [as outlined in the documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/0a/b5531ed30911d2b467006094192fe3/content.htm).

The ALV Grid keeps a reference to the table you passed to it during initialization. You update the contents of that original table and then tell the Grid to update itself.

Comment: When i don't have parameter to change the content of the table

Comment: I don’t understand your question - oh wait, that wasn’t a question at all. The ALV Grid keeps a reference to the table you passed to it during initialization. You update the contents of that original table and then tell the Grid “Yo man, there’s new data there, go update yourself”.

Comment: YOu have right thanks this the answer that i expect tghanks , write that inside and i validate it and see this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637681/abap-change-text-button-and-function-in-runtime